# How do I get VS Code Sorbet to find the right bundler version?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sorbet

The error I'm seeing in the output:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.3.25) required by your /Users/amirsharif/Projects/sendapostcardonline/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.3.25`
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
[Error - 10:42:32 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
Running Sorbet LSP with:
    bundle exec srb typecheck --lsp --disable-watchman
```

It seems that Sorbet is using the wrong Ruby version.
Is there a way I can force it to use the right one?

Answer (score 1):

I restarted VS Code and it seems to work now.